# Show that $f : X → \Bbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if $\{x ∈ X : f(x) > r\}$ is measurable for every $r ∈ \Bbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory

$f  : X → \Bbb{R}$ is a function on a measurable space $(X, χ)$.  I want to show that $f : X → \Bbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if $\{x ∈ X : f(x) > r\}$ is measurable for every $r ∈ \Bbb{Q}$.

I know, given alpha, I need to choose $r_n ∈ \Bbb{Q}$ with $r_n$ bring a decreasing sequence in $\Bbb{Q}$ but I'm unsure where to go from here. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE!, I assume you might have struggled writing this question that is why I recommend you to learn Jax when writing mathematical formula follow this link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing function is measurable iff it's measurable for each rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823102/showing-function-is-measurable-iff-its-measurable-for-each-rational)

Answer (score 1):

Given $r \in \mathbb{R}$, choose a sequence $(q_n)$ of rationals such that $q_n \searrow r$. Then
$$\{f > r\} = \bigcup_n \{f > q_n\}$$ so $\{f  > r\}$ is measurable.